# Hermitian Property of a Householder Transform on a Complex Field

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, reflection

Let $\mathbf{H}$ be a Householder (i.e. elementary reflector), such that $\mathbf{Hx} = \mathbf{e}_1$, for an $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{C}^n$, having $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1$.

For this I have defined $\mathbf{H} = e^{i\theta}\left(\mathbf{I} - 2\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^*}{\mathbf{u}^*\mathbf{u}}\right)$, where $e^{i\theta} = \frac{\overline{x_1}}{|x_1|}$ and $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{x} - e^{i\theta}\|\mathbf{x}\|_2\mathbf{e}_1$.  I am indeed getting the expected result of $\mathbf{Hx} = \mathbf{e}_1$, but my trouble is figuring out how to enforce the property that $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{H}^*$.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I have also checked that this $\mathbf{H}$ is unitary, since $\mathbf{H}^* = \mathbf{H^{-1}} = e^{-i\theta}\left(\mathbf{I} - 2\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^*}{\mathbf{u}^*\mathbf{u}}\right)$ and $\mathbf{H}^*\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{I}$, but again, I don't see how $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{H^{-1}}$.  I even get that $\mathbf{H}^{-1}\mathbf{e}_1 = \mathbf{x}$, which should be expected.

Any help is really well appreciated.

Comment: A Householder reflection $H$ by definition is a linear operator that is a reflection ($x\mapsto-x$) on some one-dimensional subspace and an identity map on the orthogonal hyperplane. So, by definition, it must be Hermitian. It follows that if $Hx=y$, then $x^\ast y\ (=x^\ast Hx)$ must be real. In your case, if $x_1$ is not real, $H$ simply does not exist. If $x_1$ is real instead, then $e^{i\theta}=1$ and your problem is automatically resolved.

Comment: @user1551 To corroborate what you have kindly provided, then, I can't build an $\mathbf{H}$ with the Hermitian property if the working field is complex, right?

Comment: Sometimes you can and sometimes you cannot. That depends on whether $x_1$ (the first element of $x$ is real). You can always construct $H$ in the way outlined in your question, but unless $e^{i\theta}$ is real, the resulting $H$ is not Hermitian (and strictly speaking, it is not a reflection either). Rather it is a complex scalar multiple of a Hermitian unitary matrix.

Comment: Summary for me: unitarity remains, important for QR decomposition ... $\theta$ is not defined for $x_1=0$, would also be numerically more stable to derive it from $H(\theta=0)x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always possible to construct a Householder reflection that maps a prespecified unit vector in $\mathbb C^n$ to another.

A Householder reflection $H$, **by definition**, is a linear operator whose restrictions are $-\operatorname{Id}$ on $V$ and $\operatorname{Id}$ on $V^\perp$ for some one-dimensional subspace $V\subseteq\mathbb C^n$. For any $x,y\in\mathbb C^n$, if we write $x=u_x+v_x$ and $y=u_y+v_y$ where $u_x,u_y\in V^\perp$ and $v_x,v_y\in V$, then
$$
\langle Hx,y\rangle
=\langle u_x-v_x,u_y+v_y\rangle
=\langle u_x,u_y\rangle - \langle v_x,v_y\rangle
=\langle u_x+v_x,u_y-v_y\rangle
=\langle x,Hy\rangle.
$$
It follows that $H$ is necessarily Hermitian. Being Hermitian is not an optional property, but a must.

Consequently, if $y=Hx$ for some unit vectors $x$ and $y$, then $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,Hx\rangle$ must be real. In other words, **you can construct a Householder reflection that maps $x$ to $y$ only when $\langle x,y\rangle$ is real.**

This is an often neglected point. People usually only deal with Householder reflection over the reals. Since $\langle x,y\rangle$ is real in this case, they don't realise that the story is a bit different over $\mathbb C$.

In your case, if you want $Hx=e_1$, we need $\langle x,e_1\rangle=x_1$ to be real. If $x_1$ is not real, you cannot construct $H$. If $x_1$ is real instead, then $e^{i\theta}=1$ and all apparent difficulties in your question vanish. The construction is then analogous to that over $\mathbb R$. Just replace any matrix/vector transpose by conjugate transpose.

Some people do try to generalise Householder reflection in the real case to the complex case in a similar manner to your question. **Now the construction is always possible**. However, the resulting $H$ in general is neither Hermitian nor a reflection, but a complex scalar multiple of a Hermitian Householder reflection.